# How to specify secretEnv to cloudbuild.yaml via gcloud cli args or environment variables

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-kms, google-secret-manager

If I follow the cloud build [document](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials?hl=ja), I have to specify encrypted secret on cloudbuild.yaml.

```
secrets:
- kmsKeyName: projects/[PROJECT-ID]/locations/global/keyRings/[KEYRING-NAME]/cryptoKeys/[KEY-NAME]
  secretEnv:
    MY_SECRET: <base64-encoded encrypted secret>
```

Even if it is encrypted, I don't commit secret value at code. Please tell me another way.

ex. via args from gcloud builds submit command or environment variables,...etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Google Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) instead. We're still updating the documentation, but there is an example of how you can use it with Cloud Build:

First, create a secret:

```
$ echo -n "my-secret-data" | gcloud beta secrets create "my-api-key" \
    --replication-policy "automatic" \
    --data-file -
```

Grant the Cloud Build Service Account permission to access your secret:

```
$ gcloud beta secrets add-iam-policy-binding "my-api-key" \
    --member "serviceAccount:<project-number>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
```

#### Update (February 2021)

Then retrieve the secret in your build steps:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'my-step'
  args:
  - '--secret=$$MY_SECRET'
  secretEnv:
  - 'MY_SECRET'

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - env: 'MY_SECRET'
    versionName: 'projects/my-project/secrets/my-secret/versions/latest'
```

#### Old answer (pre-February 2021)

Then retrieve the secret in your build steps:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud@sha256:c1dfa4702cae9416b28c45c9dcb7d48102043578d80bfdca57488f6179c2211b'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
       gcloud beta secrets versions access --secret=my-api-key latest > /secrets/my-api-key
  volumes:
  - name: 'secrets'
    path: '/secrets'

- name: 'my-step'
  volumes:
  - name: 'secrets'
    path: '/secrets'
  args: # ... /secrets/my-api-key contains the secret
```

Comment: How should I do specify env variables in my-step's container?

Comment: What about multiple secrets, do I have to fetch them one at a time? And why not have auto-substitution for values in Secret Manager? Where can I raise a feature request for this?

Comment: You can run that gcloud command many times (put each on its own line). A feature request for deeper Cloud Build integration has already been filed.

Comment: Hey Seth, love the work on GSM, thanks!
Regarding the above, is there any security concern that the secrets are plaintext in the /secrets volume? What if layer caching is used as with Kaniko?

Comment: That's definitely a concern and one of the reasons we advocate for having apps talk directly to SM or store in an envvar directly. The fs is the best-available portable solution today, but we're always working on product improvements

Comment: @sethvargo Is there any way to substitute the $PROJECT_ID in the versionName? I cant seem to get that to work. This is a great to see in Cloud Build now.