# Retrieving environment variables in Google Cloud stored in secret manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, bitbucket-pipelines, gcp-secret-manager

I am unable to retrieve an environment variable accessed in code in my bitbucket deployed application.
When my application starts, I want to fetch db uri, like this:
`const uri = process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI;`

Whenever I build and push the artifact from local, my environment variables are successfully passed from .env-files I have stored locally on my machine. Obviously I do not want to commit this file.

When I use Bitbucket Pipelines for deploying my application to GCP. I am able to successfully push a new artifact to GCP. But on application startup, it is unable to retrieve my db-uri.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref) article is pretty close to describing what I want to achieve, but I don't see how this addresses the fact that the property value is an actual secret that I cannot commit to my repo, and need to access at application startup from *somewhere*.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034139/access-environment-variables-stored-in-google-secret-manager-from-google-cloud-b) question describes how to access variables from secret manager in the Cloud  Pipeline, not in the application itself.

I use the predefined `google-app-engine-deploy-pipe`. Relevant parts of my bitbucket-pipelines.yml looks like this:

```
branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Deploy
          deployment: test
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:1.0.0
              variables:
                  KEY_FILE: $GCP_SECRET
                  PROJECT: 'test-project'
                  DEPLOYABLES: 'test.yaml'
                  PROMOTE: 'false'
                  STOP_PREVIOUS_VERSION: 'false'
```

The `GCP_SECRET` is the base-64-encoded GCP service account, fetched from secret inside Bitbucket, working nicely.

Inside `test.yml`, I have the following:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
instance_class: B1
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: "test"
  MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI: $MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI
```

So my issue is the `MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI`.
I have tried adding a new secret in GCP Secret Manager where I have an entry `MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI` with actual connection string, but my application is unable to find this property at startup.

Where am I going wrong? Is there something fundamental in how to pass secrets that I have misunderstood?

Can I define and pass a variable inside Bitbucket deployment pipeline? Or is the correct way to access the environment variable directly from Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by the help of [this](https://medium.com/@jorn.verhaegen/environment-variables-with-google-app-engine-and-ci-cd-pipelines-e28b2c038a95) guide

I find the solution to be a little bit hacky, but at least it works nicely for me now. Basically, I:

- Create a shell script inside my repository, defining the names of the variables I would like to populate.
- Run the script inside bitbucket pipelines, populating with my secret bitbucket deployment variables.
- The result of this script is an env.-file with the passed secret values, and is correctly passed along to my application.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you refer to this documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-access-secret-version-console) in order to **create and access a secret manager.**

This documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/using-other-products) provides resources for **using Secret Manager with various Google Cloud services.**

For instance, **Access Secret Manager secrets and expose them as environment variables or via the filesystem from Cloud Functions.** See using [Secret Manager secrets with Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets) for detailed information.

Ensure for Adding a secret version requires the Secret Manager Admin role (**roles/secretmanager.admin**) on the secret, project, folder, or organization. Roles can't be granted on a secret version.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371905/how-to-handle-secrets-in-google-app-engine) discussion on a similar question.