# "Secret is used without being defined" Error in Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager

I am trying a run a `google cloud build` with the following configuration

```
{
  "steps": [
  {
    "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud",
    "id": "Create GitHub pull request",
    "entrypoint": "bash",
    "args": [
      "-c",
       "curl -X POST -H \"Authorization:Bearer $$GH_TOKEN\" -H 'Accept:application/vnd.github.v3+json' https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo> -d '{\"head\":\"main\",\"base\":\"newbranch\", \"title\":\"NEW_PR\"}"
    ],
    "secretEnv": ["GH_TOKEN"]
}
],
"availableSecrets": {
  "secretManager": [
  {
    "versionName": "projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/password/versions/latest",
    "env": "GH_TOKEN"
  }
  ]
}
}
```

I have created a secret in the secret manager with the name `password`. When I run the build, I am getting the **error**

> invalid secrets: secretEnv "GH_TOKEN" is used without being defined

I have also checked that my `cloud build service account` is present in **Principal** and role of the **Secret Manager**.

Comment: You may refer to the [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002762/how-to-specify-secretenv-to-cloudbuild-yaml-via-gcloud-cli-args-or-environment-v).

Comment: Thanks @MousumiRoy!!. I am doing similar thing as the answer there, but it is not working for me

Comment: you may try updating authorization to `Authorization:Bearer $GH_TOKEN`