# Cloud build defines more than 100 secret values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager

I include secret during Cloud build time but it's choking with error, I believe there Is some hard limit of 100 variables on GCP Secret manager.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid build: invalid secrets: build defines more than 100 secret values
```

[Code used to submit pipeline from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60007364)

Comment: 100 secrets?? WHy so much enrty? Maybe a design issue?

Comment: Yes, we need to update the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

The limit is 100 args.
https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema

Basically each arg counts as step, same with secret values.

[image]